# Why does my table border not go all the way round the table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a 3px black solid border. For some reason, one cell does not display this border but only that of the internal TD. I guess I must have done something incorrectly, but cannot see where it is.

```css
.enumeratorstable1921 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.enumeratorstable1921 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="enumeratorstable1921">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">To be filled up by the Enumerator.</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Enumerator&rsquo;s Initials.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Males.</td>
    <td>Females.</td>
    <td>Persons.</td>
    <td>Rooms.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not really understand your problem, do you want the border to go around the whole table? Like your code is doing right now: https://jsfiddle.net/52vx7peo/ ?

Comment: @alapaah :) actually it's not ... do you see the piece missing at the right bottom corner ?

Comment: I have looked at what you have posted but it has the same problem as on my web-page. The bottom right hand cell does not have the thick border from the table, just the cell border from the TD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by the **unnecessary use of `colspan="2"` for the last cell in the top row**.

There are no actual rows with 6 cells, but by using `colspan=4` + `colspan=2`, you are making the table use 6 columns. I'm not totally sure how browsers work with rows have that fewer actual cells; it could be that they add additional placeholder cells without content.

The empty 6th cell that is (presumably) added by the browser could explain why the 5th cell of the last row is drawn using its own defined border style - because a 6th cell is added, for which the border-collapse is applied, although still in a kinda weird way.

By removing the unneeded `colspan="2"`, the problem no longer occurs:

```css
.enumeratorstable1921 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.enumeratorstable1921 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="enumeratorstable1921">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">To be filled up by the Enumerator.</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Enumerator&rsquo;s Initials.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Males.</td>
    <td>Females.</td>
    <td>Persons.</td>
    <td>Rooms.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not a colspan, it's a rowspan.

Comment: Look carefully: you use *both*

Comment: Apologies.,,,,.

Comment: I did try and vote for your answer but as I am new to this forum, I can't do.